# 2-Variable For Loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

What is the Python equivalent for this C/C++ code snippet below?

```
// The rest of the code.
for (i = 1, j = 0; i < 10, j < 19; ++i, j += 2)
{
    // The body of the loop.
}
```

Comment: Try while. BTW: it's also poor C/C++

Comment: the condition `i<10,j<19` does not do what you think.

Comment: @sbhayana26 Sorry, but that code which I wrote was wrong, and won't run.

Comment: @CoolGuy
But it just ran!

Comment: It won't run, too many values to unpack

Comment: @sbhayana26 Huh. I tried and it does not run. Could you show the code you used?

Comment: @CoolGuy
It isn't right now possible for me to do so as the code has some other error at the moment. #And I'm sorry for that!
Anyways, I decided to go with Ahsanul Haque's response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
for i,j in zip(range(1,10),range(0,19,2)):
```

You have two things to understand:

- How range() works
- How zip() works

range takes 3 params. Start,End and increment.

First one is inclusive and second is exclusive,3rd is just like increment in c/c++.

```
range(1,10)
```

As first one is inclusive it will start from 1, and as 2nd one is exclusive it will end at 9. Default increment is one.

```
range(0,19,2)
```

As you wanted, the loop will start from 0 and end at 18 and increment by 2.

Comment: Note that this is different than the C code that was posted as the final loop iteration in that case has `i=10, j=18` whereas your's will stop after `i=9, j=16`

Comment: @Duncan that's what my much less pythonic answer is about ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Translate the "2-Variable For Loop" step by step from C/C++ into python (take care of the trap <sup>[1]</sup>):

```
# loop initialization 
i = 1
j = 0

# loop condition
while (j < 19):

    # The body of the loop.

    # loop increment
    i +=1
    j +=2
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> The C/C++ snippet has a "trap", see the [live demo](https://ideone.com/HWnwmw) Explanation: All the parts of the for loop (initialisation, condition, increment) are evaluated sequentially, but whereas in init and inc are done for its side effects, the purpose of the  condition is to get a boolean value. Both parts of the condition get evaluated each loop, but only the second (because last) is taken as the actual loop condition (the result of the first is just thrown away).

Comment: This will *work*, but it's not remotely Pythonic. Python best practice, like C/C++ best practice, is to keep the code for loop accounting grouped together and not straddling both sides of the actual iterated business logic. The best Python for what the OP probably *meant* is as in the other answers: `for i, j in zip(range(1,10), range(0,19,2)):`. The Python for what the OP has written involves itertools: `for i, j in zip(it.count(1), range(0,19,2)):`.

Comment: Also, your explanation of the `i<10,j<19` check is unclear - the way you've worded it makes it sound like the whole condition is checked exactly twice in the lifetime of the program. I think what you meant to say is that both the `i<10` and `j<19` parts are tested at each iteration, but the overall result is exactly the result of the second part, and the result of `i<10` is ignored.

Comment: Thanks @lvc for reading, I tried to clarify. All you say about python and C/C++ style is absolutely true. That was my first impression I left as a comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
for i,j in zip(range(1, 10), range(0, 19, 2)):
    # the body
```

Comment: I think this is not easy to understand for this kind of C/C++ programmer ;-) but I've learned something new :-)

Comment: Maybe the C/C++ trap in the question? (BTW: I voted up)